# node.js unavailable via ssh

Tags: node.js, bash, ssh

I am trying to call an installation of node.js on a remote server running Ubuntu via SSH. Node has been installed via nvm.

SSHing in and calling node works just fine:

```
user@localmachine:~$ ssh user@remoteserver
(Server welcome text)
user@remoteserver:~$ which node
/home/user/.nvm/v0.10.00/bin/node
```

However if I combine it into one line:

```
user@localmachine:~$ ssh user@remoteserver "which ls"
/bin/ls
user@localmachine:~$ ssh user@remoteserver "which node"
```

No sign of node, so I tried sourcing .bashrc and waiting 10 seconds:

```
user@localmachine:~$ ssh user@remoteserver "source ~/.bashrc; sleep 10; which node"
```

Only node seems affected by this. One thing I did notice was that if I ssh in and then check which shell I'm in it says `-bash` whilst if I ssh direct it gives me `/bin/bash`. I tried running the commands inside a bash login shell:

```
user@localmachine:~$ ssh user@remoteserver 'bash --login -c "which node"'
```

Still nothing.

Basically my question is: **Why isn't bash finding my node.js installation when I call it non-interactively from SSH?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ ssh user@remoteserver "which node"
```

When you run `ssh` and specify a command to be run on the remote system, ssh by default doesn't allocate a PTY (pseudo-TTY) for the session. Not having a TTY causes your remote shell process (ie, bash) to initialize as a non-interactive session instead of an interactive session. This can alter how it interprets your initialization files--.bashrc, .bash_profile, and so on.

The actual problem is probably that the line which adds `/home/user/.nvm/v0.10.00/bin` to your command PATH isn't executing for non-interactive sessions. There are two ways to resolve this:

1. Find the command in your initialization file(s) which adds `/home/user/.nvm/v0.10.00/bin` to your command path, figure out why it's not running for non-interactive sessions, and correct it.
2. Run `ssh` with the `-t` option. This tells it to allocate a PTY for the remote session. Or add the line `RequestTTY yes` to your `.ssh/config` file on the local host.

Comment: I've run it as ssh -t user@remoteserver "which node", but it still doesn't find it. Adding RequestTTY to the .ssh/config file seems to have no effect either.

Comment: I've also tried  ssh -t user@remoteserver "bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc -c 'which node'" which doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: I've just tried: 
ssh -t user@remoteserver 'export NVM_DIR="/home/user/.nvm"; [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"; which node' and that's working!

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to run bash in interactive mode with the `-i` flag:

```
user@localmachine:~$ ssh user@remoteserver "bash -i -c 'which node'"
/home/user/.nvm/v0.10.00/bin/node
```